# Motherboard beeping every 60 seconds (Gigabyte/AMI)

Tags: motherboard, bios

On occasion, my motherboard's speaker gives off a short, high-pitched beep during normal operation, continuously and in intervals of exactly 60 seconds. I do not have any other symptoms, the computer is stable with uptimes exceeding 40 days. The beeping doesn't happen throughout; it might go on for an hour or two, or just happen for around 5 minutes before a longer break.

My board is a Gigabyte X79-UD3 with AMI BIOS version F20 (latest). Neither the manual, nor any beep code references I found online, explain the meaning of regular beeps during normal computer operation after POST.

Several factors led me to believe that the cause could be overheating of the CPU or other components. The highly regular, but not uninterrupted beeping would fit an underlying sensor reading, and it would explain why I didn't notice any other issues so far. Also, the only reference I could find to [repeated beeps while running](http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/awardbeep.htm), although referring to Award BIOS, is given as "Overheated CPU". More anecdotally, this is the second year in a row that I never noticed the beeping during winter, and have it start again around May (although it should be noted that the apartment is currently often cooler in the morning than it was for a lot of winter, yet the beeping still happens).

Since last encountering this problem, I have replaced my CPU fan with a bigger (and quieter) model. I have been running Open Hardware Monitor and HWiNFO to see if there is any overheating. However, after four hours of intermittent beeping, the maximum temperature value ever registered by any CPU core was 49°C. Other motherboard components don't exceed 50°C (apart from voltage regulators which are stable between 71-77°C), hard drives register up to 45°C. I didn't notice that the beeping would coincide with any noticeable temperature spikes either. I have also done a RAM check for good measure, with no issues detected. The beeping also happens when I run a Linux Live DVD instead of my regular Windows 7 setup. For what it's worth, I have in the meantime also replaced my video card, without any effect on the beeping.

**Update:** Using Prime95 stress tests, I can get the cores to heat up to around 60-65°C, but I have to conclude that it's not a reliable way to reproduce the beeping, making overheating even less likely to be the cause. In fact the beeping resumed almost instantly after the cores had cooled down to idle levels again.

Are there any other diagnostic measures that could help me figure out what is causing the beeps?

Comment: Is it definitely originating from the motherboard?

Comment: @Paul Good question – I'm not sure how I could precisely locate the source. Apart from the PSU and hard drives, the only other devices in the case are an audio card (Asus Xonar D2X) and a Blu-ray writer (LG BH10LS30). I couldn't find out yet if any of those even contain the necessary components to produce a beep.

Comment: Why not Google for the beep codes and see what might be going on.

Comment: @DanielSaner Well, I meant originating from inside the case as opposed to the speakers.  It beeps during normal operation, so POST is complete, which means it isn't a standard POST beep.  If it were coming from the speakers it could be something else.  Is your keyboard wireless?

Comment: @Paul The beeps originate from the case. I do have a wired keyboard, but a wireless mouse. I'll try removing all of my other USB devices, too, and see if I can get the beeping to stop. Thanks for the suggestion!